# What is the reason for Item Status = "canceled" and not able to create Invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, items, status

The ordered placed by online payment, and the ordered page item status canceled,

> may i know what is the reason for my item status canceled

```
How create Invoice for this order?
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to know what is the logic behind order **item status canceled**

Then refer this class and its method  `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item :: getStatusId`

```
public function getStatusId()
{
    $backordered = (float)$this->getQtyBackordered();
    if (!$backordered && $this->getHasChildren()) {
    $backordered = (float)$this->_getQtyChildrenBackordered();
    }
    $canceled    = (float)$this->getQtyCanceled();
    $invoiced    = (float)$this->getQtyInvoiced();
    $ordered     = (float)$this->getQtyOrdered();
    $refunded    = (float)$this->getQtyRefunded();
    $shipped     = (float)$this->getQtyShipped();

    $actuallyOrdered = $ordered - $canceled - $refunded;

    if (!$invoiced && !$shipped && !$refunded && !$canceled && !$backordered) {
    return self::STATUS_PENDING;
    }
    if ($shipped && $invoiced && ($actuallyOrdered == $shipped)) {
    return self::STATUS_SHIPPED;
    }

    if ($invoiced && !$shipped && ($actuallyOrdered == $invoiced)) {
    return self::STATUS_INVOICED;
    }

    if ($backordered && ($actuallyOrdered == $backordered) ) {
    return self::STATUS_BACKORDERED;
    }

    if ($refunded && $ordered == $refunded) {
    return self::STATUS_REFUNDED;
    }

    if ($canceled && $ordered == $canceled) {
    return self::STATUS_CANCELED;
    }

    if (max($shipped, $invoiced) < $actuallyOrdered) {
    return self::STATUS_PARTIAL;
    }

    return self::STATUS_MIXED;
}
```

Here `$this->getQtyCanceled()` shows the value of **`sales_flat_order_item` tables column `qty_canceled`**

Comment: I get confused, may i know the reason why item status canceled?

Comment: @Rathinam might be there is some code in third party module that doing this things, or you have coded that way